# Ubuntu 16.04 cannot hibernate after type the sudo pm-hibernate

Tags: 16.04, swap, hibernate

My PC is OMEN by HP Laptop, and the RAM is 8GB, my SWAP space is 20GB which is more than twice of my RAM, every time when I type the command: `sudo pm-hibernate`, the screen would turn off for one or two seconds, after that, it would turn back on, and seems nothing happened.

I have check the hibernate session, and it is successful. In fact, my previous `SWAP` space is 8GB, and I have added the space of `SWAP`, and now it is 20GB, and I think it is pretty enough. The version of kernel is updated, and I have tried all the ways of this link:[Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818779/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-hibernate), so, can you guys help me to resolve it asap? Cause it is actually important for me!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Open the Terminal by pressing Ctrl+Alt+t or by searching for terminal in the Dash.

Type sudo systemctl hibernate into the terminal and press Enter.

Enter your password when prompted.
```

if it turns on again

If hibernate doesn't work:

```
Check if your swap partition is at least as large as your available RAM.

The presence of btrfs partitions has proved to make hibernation fail, so check that you're not using any btrfs partitions. Besides removing or reformatting such partitions, you may need to remove the btrfs-tools package:

sudo apt purge btrfs-tools
```

Comment: When I type the command: sudo systemctl hibernate as you said above, the screen turns off longer, but it still turns back on with screen locked.

Comment: try this command sudo apt purge btrfs-tools

Comment: actually, I did not install the btrfs-tools