# Hibernate not working in 18.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, 18.04, swap, hibernate

When I use the command `sudo systemctl hibernate`, the system seems to go to hibernation, but when restarted, it is a fresh start without any of the previous windows that were left open.

And when I tried `sudo pm-hibernate` it says `sudo: pm-hibernate: command not found`.

Here is my drive configuration if that helps:

/dev/sda = SSD with Windows 10 only (Windows C drive and the reserved partition).

/dev/sdb = HDD with NTFS and EXT4 partitions containing regular data only, no OS here currently.

/dev/sdc = SSD (GPT partition) with Ubuntu 18.04 (/ partition), swap area and a shared NTFS game drive.

GRUB is installed on /dev/sda.

**EDIT:**
I created a new parition table on /dev/sdc using **msdos** instead of **GPT**. Then I reinstalled Ubuntu and installed GRUB on /dev/sdc. After these changes, `sudo hibernate` seems to be working.

**ANOTHER EDIT:**
Because `sudo hibernate` seems to go to hibernation without locking the screen (i.e. anyone could turn on the PC and automatically be logged in), I added this line to `/etc/sudoers` (*cln* is my username):

```
cln ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/hibernate
```

and made this executable script:

```
#!/bin/bash

xdg-screensaver lock
sudo hibernate
```

Now I am able to just double-click on this script, select *Run*, and directly go to hibernation while also locking the screen. Much more comfortable.

Answer (score 4):

This instruction worked for my Ubuntu 18.04 installation.

1. `sudo apt install hibernate` It will install hibernate and other dependencies which are needed to hibernate
2. `grep swap /etc/fstab` (find UUID)
3. `sudoedit /etc/default/grub`
   At the line GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" add UUID of swap.

   The line looks like this

   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=<UUID of swap>"`

   You can choose

   ```
   `quiet splash` will hide the boot screen output

   `splash` will display the boot screen output
   ```
4. `sudo update-grub`
5. Restart, and after restart `sudo systemctl hibernate`. If everything works ok add menu entry's.
6. `sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`
   now paste this:

> [Re-enable hibernate by default in upower] Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate ResultActive=yes [Re-enable
> hibernate by default in logind] Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
> ResultActive=yes

7. Restart the computer
8. Install https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/

Comment: Tried till step 5. Not working. The GRUB line is this:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="cgroup_enable=memory swapaccount=1 resume=<UUID>"`

Is there anything wrong with this, or need I use the exact line you said (with quiet splash)?

Also, this is shown when used `grep swap /etc/fstab`:

`# swap was on /dev/sdb2 during installation`

Is that anything to be concerned about?

Comment: Update: I tried with `quiet splash resume=<UUID>` instead, but still didn't work.

Comment: My grub
   

    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=32564c12-47c9-449c-8fe3-d4ce2e170803"

My fstab:

    # swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
    UUID=32564c12-47c9-449c-8fe3-d4ce2e170803 none            swap    sw  

            0       0

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

This thread didn't solve my problem. I had to add `pci=nomsi` just before `resume=`.

take a look at this: [Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't hibernate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818779/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-hibernate/849167#849167)